# hazelcast client module for node.js

Tags: node.js, hazelcast

In my Node.js application I wanted to connect the Hazelcast node instance and access the Queue/Hashmap of Hazelcast Node. Is there any node.js module available to do this .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please, consider to choose my answer as a correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought this question was asked over a year ago, some things have changed.
[Hazelcast Node.js client](http://hazelcast.org/clients/node-js/) in fact does exist and currently provides following features

- implementation of [Open Client Binary Protocol](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/HazelcastOpenBinaryClientProtocol-Version1.0-Final.pdf)
- Map

  - Get
  - Put
  - Remove
- Smart Client - clients connect to each cluster node. 
  Since each data partition uses the well known and **consistent hashing algorithm**, **each client** can send an operation to the **relevant cluster node**, which increases the overall **throughput and efficiency**. The client doesn't need to be restarted in case of adding or removing nodes from the cluster.
- Distributed Object Listener
- Lifecycle Service

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no node.js library for Hazelcast. Some of the functionality is exposed through Memcached btw.